# Laravel Sessions with Ajax

Tags: ajax, session, laravel, simultaneous-calls

Im using Laravel to build an app and Im using the Database driver to store sessions.

The app is mostly a single page app.
With ALL content loaded via Ajax requests.

The app works perfectly fine locally in WAMP.
I can click on everything and everything just works.

However, once I upload it to the server.
Im only ever able to make ONE ajax call.

Any subsequent calls after that log me out, and bring up the login screen, in place of my AJAX loaded content.

Does anyone have any idea how I hold sessions when executing multiple / possibly simultaneous AJAX requests.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your sessions aren't being saved to the database, have you verified this?

Comment: Yeah they are being saved just fine.  The site worked fine when I was just doing regular page serving.  Now that Ive converted the site to single page and AJAX, sessions have gone all screwy.  Do I need to perhaps send the session cookie along with the AJAX requests?